# How do I convert '2020-10-31T00:00:00.0000000' from factor to date in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to draw a scatter plot with dates on the x-axis. In order to use the "scale_x_date()" function, I need to convert those dates from *factor* type to *date* type.

```
>dataset$Date
2018-12-31T00:00:00.0000000 2019-09-15T00:00:00.0000000 2019-09-28T00:00:00.000000 ...

>class(dataset$Date)
"factor"
```

Please, consider that I would like to remove time information from my data.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
# generate factor 
x <- factor(c("2018-12-31T00:00:00.0000000", "2019-09-15T00:00:00.0000000", "2019-09-28T00:00:00.000000"))

# convert to dates
as.Date(x)

# generates - "2018-12-31" "2019-09-15" "2019-09-28"
# class(as.Date(x))
## "Date"
```

Comment: Hello. No, It doesn't.
It should be something like
`
as.Date(dataset$Date, format=....)
`
I am not able to understand which is the format I should insert.

Thanks

Comment: @Giovanni - the code does generate a date variable. If this does not work for your example, I'd suggest including your specific code so that we can establish what isn't working correctly for you.

Comment: @Giovanni - What format are you after? Here's a blog post which shows you how to format a date the way you need - https://www.r-bloggers.com/date-formats-in-r/